# Efficient way to parse a <font> tag attributes using ActionScript 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I'm curious how, in ActionScript 3, to parse the font attributes of an HTML formatted content string. Lets take the following example content string:

```
var content:String = '<font face="Archer-Bold" size="12" color="#000000">My Content</font>';
```

I'd like to parse that string and create an object with the font attributes in it. So a resulting object would trace the following:

```
trace( fontInfo.name ); // output: "Archer-Bold"
trace( fontInfo.size ); // output: "12"
trace( fontInfo.color ); // output: "#000000"
```

I'm guessing regular expressions is the way to go, but I know nothing about them. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. It is ideal job for regular expressions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="onComplete();">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
            private var targets:Array = new Array();
            private function onComplete():void {

                var face:String = null;
                var size:String = null;
                var color:String = null;

                var content:String = '<font face="Archer-Bold" size="12" color="#000000">My <br> Content</font>';

                // since the content has invalid XML <br> tag XML construction will fail:
                //var x:XML = new XML(content);

                var faces:Array = content.match(/face\s*=\s*["'](.[^"']*)["']/);
                // array is null if no matches found:
                if ( faces != null ) {
                    face = faces[1];
                }

                var sizes:Array = content.match(/size\s*=\s*["'](\d{1,})["']/);
                // array is null if no matches found:
                if ( sizes != null ) {
                    size = sizes[1];
                }

                var colors:Array = content.match(/color\s*=\s*["'](.[^"']*)["']/);
                // array is null if no matches found:
                if ( colors != null ) {
                    color = colors[1];
                }

                Alert.show("Font : " + face + ", " + size + ", " + color + "." );
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an xml object?  For example:

```
var fontnode:XML = new XML(content);
trace(fontnode.@face);
trace(fontnode.@size);
trace(fontnode.@color);
```

Comment: This method will fail if the content contains some invalid markup, i.e. "My <br> content"